# Google Analytics - Traffic Drop After SSL Tracking Change

Tags: google-analytics

I recently change the tracking code on a website and visitors etc seem to have dropped by quite some margin, either the old code was inflating the figures or the new code isn't tracking all the content. The change I made was meant to offer better tracking across subdomains because I added a secure area (https://secure.). Can anyone help me explain the drop please?

My new code currently looks like :

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-9396xxx-1']); 
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.domainname.co.uk']); 
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); 

  (function() { 
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; 
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); 
  })();
```

Comment: Oh, my bounce rate has also dropped, pages per visit is up and so is average duration.

Answer (score 0):

Have your page views stayed pretty much the same? If so, the dropping bounce rate etc seem to indicate that before when a visitor went to a subdomain after visiting the main site, it was counted as a new visit, but now is tracked (correctly) as part of the same visit.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely what you were experiencing before the update was Google Analytics defaulting to setting cookies for each subdomain separately.  The following code exemplifies this behavior:

Google Analytics defaults to the behavior below on www.domainname.co.uk:

```
// Sets cookie to be accessible to only www.domainname.co.uk
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'www.domainname.co.uk']);
```

Google Analytics defaults to the behavior below on secure.domainname.co.uk:

```
// Sets cookie to be accessible to only secure.domainname.co.uk
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'secure.domainname.co.uk']);
```

"secure" doesn't have access to "www" cookies per browser secutiry precautions so that you can't for example access cookies by default between say customer1.shoppingcart.com and customer2.shoppingcart.com. Thus originally, the "secure" _trackPageview didn't have access to your "www" cookie data, so your visits/visitors were duplicated in your original implementation.

The new code above looks correct per the [Google Analytics Documentation - Tracking Multiple Domains](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite).

```
// Set cookie accessible to www & secure
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.domainname.co.uk']);
```